# Toolbar Navigation Link

Tags: swiftui, ios16

With the new navigation logic starting with iOS 16 how are you supposed to upgrade navigationBarItems to toolbar? My app has a number of views with a plus button on the upper right corner of the view that link to new views. Below are the old style with **navigationBarItems** and new style with **toolbar**. In the example below in **MyNewView** I'm not sure how to handle the navigation link. It gives a warning that the navigation link initializer is unused.

```
struct MyOldView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("The Old View")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Our Old View")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink (destination: GoToNewView()) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
        })
    }
}

struct MyNewView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("The New View")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Our New View")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button( action: {

                    NavigationLink("", destination: GoToNewView())

                }){
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GoToNewView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Here is our new view")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The NavigationLink can’t be in the action of the button that is a void not a view builder

Comment: So how do I handle my former link?

Comment: Just search "NavigationLink" and "toolbar" on SO you will find several different configurations

Answer (score 3):

A `NavigationLink` is a `View` and can’t be passed as the `action` closure of the `Button` initializer. Since `NavigationLink` acts as a button you could just add a `NavigationLink` without the `Button`:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    NavigationLink(destination: GoToNewView()) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
    }
 }
```